# Add TabPages to Tab Control in Visual Studio 2010 Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wtl

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional, and created a WTL Project (Dialog). In this dialog, I inserted a Tab Control via the Toolbox. However, after placing it on the dialog window in the Designer/Resource Editor, I just can't add any tabs. There are several issues:

- In some video tutorials and the MSDN, it says that the Tab Control starts with two tabs, which switch when clicked. However, the Designer shows five tabs, which don't switch when I click them.
- Aforementioned tutorials also suggest to edit the TabPages property in the property pane. However, I can't find such a property in the property pane.
- When running the Test Dialog (found in the Format menu), the five tabs are visible, and they are also focused/switched when clicked. However, running the program, there's only the plain Tab Control pane without any tabs (white square).

How can I add a Tab into the Tab Control via the Designer, i.e. not dynamical?

Comment: I am using [visual studio 2013 community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx); and see the same behavior. I think you cannot do what you have in mind. Tab pages must be added using source code.  Which tutorials are you referring to?

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233654%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and one [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OEiGMri7o4), though it's in Visual Basic, but the Designer should be the same. I can't find the other tutorial right now, but surprisingly there's [another video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LSqZ7Kl6CE), which seems quite helpful and I couldn't find earlier. Looks like it's indeed not possible how I had it in mind when using C++.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be good stackoverflowers and answer the question properly.

The visual basic tutorials do not show the same dialog resource editor you are using for your WTL project.  Although, the video tutorial that is most closely related shows how to add a tab control using this editor; it does so by altering the MFC code.  It runs the program to show the result; it does not show the tab inside the resource editor.

Thus, the conclusion is that tabs cannot be added using the dialog editor on its own.